# What is the purpose of Dispatcher CheckAccess?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, dispatcher

On Async webservice on complete event, there is a code such as:

```
Debug.Assert(Dispatcher.CheckAccess()); // don't do marshaling here- it's already runinng on UI thread!
```

Does anybody know what happens if I remove this code?
Or, able answer my questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a debugging assertion.  Removing it will have no effect on production code.

What it's doing, though, is using [Dispatcher.CheckAccess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess.aspx) to verify that you are on the UI thread during the exectution at that point.  If you call that method from a background thread, the assertion will fail.

Removing this may have an impact on your ability to debug that in the future.